# How to retrieve a value from a cell into a URL

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to send out SMS using an API
http://bulksms.mysmsmantra.com:8080/WebSMS/SMSAPI.jsp?username=username&password=password&sendername=sender id&mobileno=919999999999&message=Hello

I want to get the mobileno from a cell in sheet7 of the workbook from "d" the cursor will be in the same row. just want the value from "d" to be picked up and used as mobile no.

I found a code which works well with hard coded number in the mobileno, but getting an error when I try to pull the value. Any help will be appreciated

```
Sub SendSms()    
    Dim URL As String
    Dim rng As Range

    URL = "http://bulksms.mysmsmantra.com:8080/WebSMS/SMSAPI.jsp?username=username&password=password&sendername=sender id&mobileno=& ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(7).rng.Row("d:d").Value & "&message=Hi test"

    Dim xml As Object
    Set xml = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    xml.Open "GET", URL, False
    xml.Send
End Sub
```

I require the code to pull the value from "d:d:" to be picked and used as mobileno and sms to be sent out.

ps; I am a VBA novice, so sorry if I haven't explained it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

First of all there is a quote missing right after `id&mobileno=` it must be:

```
Url = "http://bulksms.mysmsmantra.com:8080/WebSMS/SMSAPI.jsp?username=username&password=password&sendername=sender id&mobileno=" & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(7).Rng.Row("d:d").Value & "&message=Hi test"
```

Secondly this is no valid address to a cell `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(7).Rng.Row("d:d").Value`. Because `d:d` is a whole column but you can only put one single cell value into the URL but not a whole column.

So you either must use a concrete cell like

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(7).Range("D1").Value
```

Or you need to loop through column D to send a SMS for each number in column D.
Note: *I won't explain that further because you will find a ton of tutorials how to loop through a column.*

Also note that `Worksheets(7)` is the 7ᵗʰ worksheet in the tab list. If someone re-aranges the tabs then your code will fail. Might be better to use the tab name `Worksheets("MySheetName")`.

Comment: entered it as this  Url = "http://bulksms.mysmsmantra.com:8080/WebSMS/SMSAPI.jsp?username=username&password=password&sendername=sender id&mobileno= " & Worksheets("MonthlyAttendance").rng.Row("d1474").Value & "&message=Hi test" and got error. Object doesn't support this property or method (Error 438).

Comment: Because you did not use the correct syntax as I explained: `rng.Row("d1474")` does not exist. It must be `Worksheets("MonthlyAttendance").Range("D1474").Value`.

Comment: oops. got it. but how would i get the value without defining a cell number . as i wish to get it from the row that the cursor is it from the column D

Comment: You can use `Range("D" & ActiveCell.Row)` to get the row of the active cell.